# Adapter response isn't displayed in a Dojo ListItem

Tags: dojo, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I am using a Worklight adapter to get the RSS Feed from a web site; the adapter gets me the data in XML format, but the problem is I can't display the data in a Dojo LisItem.

These are the JS functions to call the Adapter:

```
function loadFeedsSuccess(result) {
    console.log("Data sucesfully downloaded, HTTP " + result.status);
    if(result.invocationResult.Items.length > 0) {
        console.log("Server has returned " + result.invocationResult.Items.length + " item(s)"); displayRSSFeed(result.invocationResult.Items);
    } 
}

function loadFeedsFailure(result) {
    console.log("Error while loading RSS feed: " + result.errorMessage);
}

function displayRSSFeed(rawData) {
    var store = new dojo.store.Memory({data:rawData, idProperty: "guid"});
    require(["dijit/registry"], function(registry){ var newsList = registry.byId("newsList"); dojo.empty("newsList");
    store.query(function(news){
        var newsItem = dojox.mobile.ListItem({label:news.title}); newsList.addChild(newsItem); }); 
    });
}

function getNewsInit() {    
    var invocationData = {
        adapter: "FeedReader",
        procedure: "getStoriesFiltered"
    };
    var options = { 
        onSuccess: loadFeedsSuccess,
        onFailure: loadFeedsFailure
    };

    WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, options); 
}
```

The Browser doesn't diplay the data an shows the following Error:

```
[/NewsApp/apps/services/api/News/common/query] exception. ReferenceError: dojo is not defined worklight.js:4673
Uncaught ReferenceError: dojo is not defined
```

Any one have any idea how to fix my Problem?

Comment: did you try to move all the dojo initialisations to `wlCommonInit`?

Comment: also try to add this script in your html and test `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8/dojo/dojo.js"></script>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you're using Dojo and setting the `async` configuration property to `true`, then the `dojo` namespace is no longer available. This means that you can't use `dojo.store.Memory` or `dojox.mobile.ListItem` anymore.

To solve that issue you either have to disable the `async` function or use AMD to load your modules:

```js
function displayRSSFeed(rawData) {
    require([ "dijit/registry", "dojo/store/Memory", "dojox/mobile/ListItem", "dojo/dom-construct" ], function(registry, Memory, ListItem, domConstruct) {
        var store = new Memory({data:rawData, idProperty: "guid"});
        var newsList = registry.byId("newsList");
        domConstruct.empty("newsList");
        store.query(function(news){
            var newsItem = new ListItem({label:news.title});
            newsList.addChild(newsItem);
        });
    });
}
```

If it then throws the error:

```
ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

Then it means you're load loading the Dojo core at all, make sure you're loading `dojo.js`.